# Can charging a parallel plate capacitor and separating the plates be an effective way to generate a statically charged object with specified charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

Suppose I would like to generate a statically charged object containing a specified amount of charge Q so that it can be used in various experiments. If (1) I make a parallel plate capacitor and measure its capacitance C, (2) charge the capacitor with a specified voltage V and finally (3) separate the plates, would each plate contain +CV and -CV Coulombs of charge on their own once separated? If yes, how long would each plate contain that charge if supported by a hypothetically perfect insulator in air? Are there better ways to generate statically charged objects that contain a specified amount of charge Q?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you don't accidentally discharge any of the plates. This means that you have to first disconnect the plates from the circuit that connects them and then separate them.

The procedure you envision is slightly more complicated than the usual way of charging up a conductor by induction (see the question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495190/what-is-actually-being-removed-when-a-metal-conductor-is-grounded) for a nice diagram).

Comment: A charged object (with no sharp edges) in air tends tends to slowly lose charge do to ions in the air produced by background and cosmic radiation.

Comment: I agree with you there, although these effects are often neglected in introductory courses (which is the context I used to interpret the question).

Comment: Now that I think about it, warm humidity may also cause a rapid discharge. During my four years in Boston, I encountered a much higher incidence of static electricity than I do in Miami.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a known charge on a conductor by connecting it to the output of a DC power supply which has its other terminal grounded.   An (expensive) instrument called a ballistic galvanometer can measure the quantity of charge which flows quickly through it.